# How to properly print values from a nested loop in a react render() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

As you can see in my code example below which is part of a render() block in a react component, I am trying to render the value of the variable "folder" in the outer loop. Unfortunately, the code section

> `<div>{folder}</div>`

seems to be ignored. Can anyone help me in finding the right syntax that outputs the current folder value from the outer loop?

```
{
    folders.map((folder,_index1) => {

        <div>{folder}</div>

        return (
                items.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                        <div>
                        {(folder === item.folder) ?
                                <Draggable
                                key={item.id}
                                draggableId={item.id}
                                index={index}>
                                {(provided, snapshot) => (
                                <div
                                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                                    { ...provided.draggableProps }
                                    { ...provided.dragHandleProps }
                                    style={getItemStyle(
                                    snapshot.isDragging,
                                    provided.draggableProps.style
                                    )}>
                                    <div>
                                    {item.content}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                )}
                            </Draggable>
                            : null
                        } 
                        </div>

         )})
    )})
}
```

Comment: Components should have single parent node, besides you do not return `<div>{folder}</div>` so it's ignored. I'm not sure about single parent because it's not whole component.

Comment: following Zydnar comment, you could add <React.Fragment> as a single parent node, in order to avoid that problem. Besides that, I believe your render function is too complex, you should simplify it a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Zydnar's comment above:

This is what it should look like:

```
{
    folders.map((folder,_index1) => {
        return (
                <> // or <React.Fragment> with the corresponding closing tag
                    <div>{folder}</div> // this has to be part of what is returned
                    items.map((item, index) => {
                       return (
                           <div>
                             {(folder === item.folder) ?
                                ...
                </>

         )})
    )})
}
```